# Call to a member function toArray() on array in FlashMessenger

Tags: php, zend-framework2, flashmessenger

I'm getting following error in my ZF2 FlashMessenger:

*Call to a member function toArray() on array in /vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/Plugin/FlashMessenger.php on line 306*

FlashMessages will be rendered by my FlashMessageHelper:

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\View\Helper\FlashMessenger;

class FlashMessageHelper extends AbstractHelper {

  public function __invoke(FlashMessenger $flashMessenger) {

    $flashMessenger->setMessageOpenFormat('<div%s><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><p class="text-center">');

    $flashMessenger->setMessageSeparatorString('</p><p class="text-center">');

    $flashMessenger->setMessageCloseString('</p></div>');

    $flashMessenger->setAutoEscape(false);

    echo $flashMessenger->render('error', array(
        'alert',
        'alert-dismissible',
        'alert-danger'
    ));
    echo $flashMessenger->render('info', array(
        'alert',
        'alert-dismissible',
        'alert-info'
    ));
    echo $flashMessenger->render('default', array(
        'alert',
        'alert-dismissible',
        'alert-warning'
    ));
    echo $flashMessenger->render('success', array(
        'alert',
        'alert-dismissible',
        'alert-success'
    ));
  }
}
?>
```

Does anybody know about this error? This is first time, that this error occured. Google and "zend-mvc" - repo - issues says nothing about this.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

See this in ZF2 (Best Pratices):

The **Plugin FlashMessenger** , send your message to a waiting pool ( Through FlashMessenger Zend MVC **Plugin** ) which will be displayed on another page request ( Through **ViewHelper** FlashMessenger ) .

There are 4 types of messages that you can integrate with the **Bootstrap** Notifications ( **error, info , default , success** ) .

Now let's practice

In **Action** within the **Controller** , you must enter your message and your brand :

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger;

public function registerAction(){
  if($formValid){
      $this->flashMessenger()->addSucessMessage('Saved!');
  } else{
      $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Fail!');
  }

  //redirect to other route and show message
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('app');
}
```

In **View** ( .phtml ) , you only need to use :

```
#show messages of addErrorMessage();
echo $flash->render('error',   array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-danger'));
#show messages of addInfoMessage();
echo $flash->render('info',    array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-info'));
#show messages of addMessage();
echo $flash->render('default', array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-warning'));
#show messages of addSucessMessage();
echo $flash->render('success', array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-success'));
```

In **View** , if using **Bootstrap** :

```
 $flash = $this->flashMessenger();
 $flash->setMessageOpenFormat('<div>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
         &times;
     </button>
     <ul><li>')
     ->setMessageSeparatorString('</li><li>')
     ->setMessageCloseString('</li></ul></div>');


 echo $flash->render('error',   array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-danger'));
 echo $flash->render('info',    array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-info'));
 echo $flash->render('default', array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-warning'));
 echo $flash->render('success', array('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-success'));
```

Now 's a hack , if you want to view the **FlashMessages** on the screen without resquest ou redirect page ( Ideal for form errors , which you do not redirects or AJAX to another page ) , use this technique .

```
public function registerAction(){
      if($formValid){
          $this->flashMessenger()->addSucessMessage('Saved!');
      } else{
          #add to pool
          $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Fail');
          #merge message
          $feedback = array_merge(
             $this->flashMessenger->getErrorMessages(),
             $this->flashMessenger->getCurrentErrorMessages()
          );
          #clear pool
          $this->clearCurrentErrorMessages();

      }

      #message in variable to VIEW
      new ViewModel(array(
        'feedback' => $feedback,
      ));
    }

}
```

If you want to deepen better at it, follow the links Official Zend 2 documentation , gives a tried on available methods , will help a lot :

**VIEW** -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html

**CONTROLLER** -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-flashmessenger

Comment: Hi Rider, I cant see a difference to my code? Your code below **In View , if using Bootstrap :** is exactly what i do with my FlashMessageHelper. This Helper is part of many personal projects and its first time, that this error occured.